# League of Legends error

Tags: lutris

Can someone please help me I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to play league with Lutris everytime I try to install I get an error.

Here's what Lutris shows:

```
0140:fixme:process:CreateProcessInternalW Unsupported attribute 0x20002.
00da:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
00d3:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFA, 0129FF14
00da:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
00da:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({d2d578d9-2936-45b6-a09f-30e32715f42d}, 0x11a5a840, 0x155f39b8, 0x15632808) stub.
01a2:fixme:time:QueryThreadCycleTime (0x140,0x2d7fe18): stub!
00da:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  233
  Current serial number in output stream:  232
```

Comment: I reformatted your errors for readability, and saw several `wine` errors, complaining  that League of Legends uses several Windows syscalls that `wine` doesn't yet support. Check with `winehq.org`.

Comment: So what should I do ? I mean I've seen others play league of legends on linux ubuntu without such problems

Comment: Ask the others? Install Windows in a VM, and run it there? Did you check winehq.org?